# Macbook Pro (Mid 2012) stopped detecting external Monitor since the upgrade to OS X 10.15.7

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, hdmi, displayport

Macbook Pro (Mid 2012) model suddenly stopped detecting any external Monitors immediately after the recent OS X Upgrade to 10.15.7. Currently I'm using Mini Display Port to HDMI Female Adapter and connecting the Macbook to an external Dell Monitor (i.e., Dell P2419H monitor)  - the monitor reports `No HDMI signal from your device` and enters sleep mode.

I notice that this issue is being faced by number of users post-upgrade, it is frustrating that Apple didn't bother to provide a fix or a patch to this persistent issue.

Searched for a resolution on this issue and tried the suggestions (over the different sites, posts etc.,) but with no luck. Still the external display isn't working. Below are the additional details:

- Model: `Macbook Pro, Mid-2012`
- OS: OS X `10.15.7`
- Built-in Display: `Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB graphics`
- External Monitor: `Dell P2419H monitor`
- Connectors: `HDMI connector` + `Mini Display Port to HDMI Female Adapter`

---

**Troubleshooting efforts:**

Below are the list of Suggestions that I've tried (with NO SUCCESS):

- Definitely this isn't a cable or HDMI connector issue, as the same cables are working with my Windows machine. And the problem started only after the OS upgrade
- Installed `Display Link Driver for Mac` - as suggested in one of the post, though the driver got installed, it
- Removing the power cable of the monitor and restart of monitor
- Hit Restart, close the laptop lid, which on immediate closing of the lid enables the display on external monitor.
- `SMC reset` - Shift + Control + Option Key + Power button
- `NVRAM reset` - Option + Command + P + R

Would Downgrading the OS to a lower version than 10.15.7 would fix the issue ? If yes, what would be the OS version ?

Similarly I've tried few weird workarounds like restarting the Macbook N number of times - unfortunately in my cases none of them seems to fix the issue. By now I've almost spent literally months time searching for a fix, and I'm desperately looking for fixing the issue. Hope to find an answer to this issue!!

Comment: Does this also occur if you are in Boot Picker (hold Option key during boot) or Target Disk Mode (hold T during boot)?

Comment: Yeah it is occurring at Option key during boot.

Comment: It wasn’t 100% clear to me from reading your question, so I’ll ask directly: Is the display recognized if you reboot your machine with the MDP-HDMI adapter **disconnected** and only attach it **after** macOS has finished loading?

Comment: the display is not recognized after the reboot of the machine.. yes, I tried disconnecting MDP-HDMI adapter and attach it only after OS finished loading.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this, facing the same issue with my mid 2012 MacBook pro